# Get component props from component provided as another value in an interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a component that extends a sidebar component and accepts a footer component:

```
interface SidebarWithFooterProps extends SidebarProps {
    footerComponent: React.ReactNode;
}


export const SidebarWithFooter: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<SidebarWithFooterProps>> = ({
    footerComponent,
    className,
    mobile,
    ...props
}) => (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Sidebar className={clsx(classes.content, className)} mobile={mobile} {...props} />
        <div className={classes.footer}>{footerComponent}</div>
    </div>
);
```

I need to add another prop 'footerComponentProps', that allows us to provide props to pass to the footerComponent.

My problem is how to type that? How can I get the props for the provided footerComponent? I've tried with a generic:

```
interface SidebarWithFooterProps<T extends React.ReactElement> extends SidebarProps {
    footerComponent: T;
    footerComponentProps?: React.ComponentProps<T>;
}

export const SidebarWithFooter: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<SidebarWithFooterProps<React.ReactElement>>> = ({…
```

but this results in an error on `React.ComponentProps<T>`:

```
Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'JSXElementConstructor<any> | keyof IntrinsicElements'
```

(and then `SidebarWithFooterProps<React.ReactElement>` feels redundant, but needs an argument)

I'm definitely getting the generic wrong and I'm not sure what `<T extends React.ReactElement>` should be?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the generic type P for the props instead

```
interface SidebarWithFooterProps<P> extends SidebarProps {
  footerComponent: React.ReactElement<P>;
  footerComponentProps?: P;
}
```

Comment: This gives me a similar error as @Ale_Bianco's answer - essentially footerComponent cannot be used as a JSX component.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ComponentProps` has generic constraint as `T extends React.JSXElementConstructor<any> | keyof React.JSX.IntrinsicElements` so you have to set your generic constraint to something narrowed from `React.JSXElementConstructor<any> | keyof React.JSX.IntrinsicElements` or exactly `React.JSXElementConstructor<any> | keyof React.JSX.IntrinsicElements`. I chose the latter.
2. As you need to pass `FooterComponent`, you will simply add it and pass it to `SidebarWithFooter` as your `T`.

Together it will look like this:

```
type SidebarProps = {}

interface SidebarWithFooterProps<T extends React.JSXElementConstructor<any> | keyof React.JSX.IntrinsicElements> extends SidebarProps {
    footerComponent: T;
    footerComponentProps?: React.ComponentProps<T>;
}

declare const FooterComponent: React.FC<{a: string; b: number}>;

declare const SidebarWithFooter: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<SidebarWithFooterProps<typeof FooterComponent>>>;
```

You can use `SidebarWithFooter` this way:

```
<SidebarWithFooter
  footerComponent={FooterComponent}
  footerComponentProps={{
    a: 'hello',
    b: 23
  }}
/>
```

TypeScript playground - https://tsplay.dev/w6QPRW

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer - but this seems to need to know the typeof FooterComponent? (you're declaring it and then using typeof)

In my component, the footer component is supplied as a prop, so SidebarWithFooter can't use typeof FooterComponent?

Comment: If you have different components that you can pass to Sidebar, you may be interested to have a high order component that infers types for you so you don’t have to specify it as I suggested to you. If this is what you need, I can update my answer